# Oracle SQL -- Select all but entries that are blank or have spaces

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Hello and good afternoon,

I am trying to compose a query to select a number of Customer IDs. Sometimes, for whatever reason, the Customer ID (PK) might have a blank Customer Name, or a Customer Name with 4 or 5 spaces in it, but no number or letters (A name can be any string of numbers or letters, sometimes "-" as well).

How can I filter it out? My current query looks like this in addition to my other WHERE clauses. I need to ensure CustomerName isn't just a bunch of spaces, or empty. It needs to have some alphanumeric text, or a -:

```
   SELECT cust.CustomerID, cust.CustomerName
   FROM cust
   WHERE cust.StartDate Between '01-Jun-2017' AND '01-Sep-2017' AND cust.CustomerID Like '%100%' Or cust.CustomerID Like '%200%'
```

However, I want something to look like this:

```
   AND CustomerName NOT LIKE '%  %' OR != ""
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what about using `TRIM` function?

Comment: or replace `replace('  this is a test',' ',''), coalesce(replace('     ',' ',''),'x') as ExcludeMe`

Comment: why the comment about '-' do you want to do something special with it as well?

Comment: @RadimBača If you can, please see my update. The issue is that sometimes, the CustomerName field has been entered as " " or "    " or "           " and I don't want those results.

Comment: @xQbert Because the customerName can look like "11111" or "fooooo" or "fo1o1o1o" or "foo-1111"

Comment: How can I filter it out? What is "it?" all spaces? just replace the spaces only include customers that don't have a space? what?  Provide some examples of data and what you expect back.

Comment: @TonyKelly - `TRIM(customerid) is not null` is all you need. `TRIM` will trim leading and trailing spaces, and the result is `null` if the input was `null` or if it was all spaces, nothing else.

Comment: Also: Please pay attention to the difference between single and double quotes. In Oracle, strings are enclosed in single, not double quotes.

Comment: @xQbert Some "CustomerName" fields are entered as blanks ("") or as some series of spaces (" "), ("        "), ("  "); the number of spaces being arbitrary.

Thus, I don't want to select the rows where the CustomerName field is blank, OR where it only contains spaces, thus my desire to use "NOT LIKE", but I can't seem to find syntax that works with that.

Comment: @mathguy can you post this as a full-blown response? your answer worked perfectly...I didn't know I could put TRIM(CustomerName) IS NOT NULL in my select statement. Could you possibly show me proper syntax for it?

Comment: I don't understand: in the question you said blank **Customer Number**, did you mean Customer Name? In any case, what you want is EXACTLY Customer Name is blank OR it contains only spaces, what do you mean by "that is **not** what you want"?

Comment: @mathguy I messed up writing Name/Number...that is my fault for adding ambiguity. I will change momentarily.

What I want is to exclude the rows where the CustomerNumber field is only spaces, or blank. Simple as that. To NOT select them, but select every other (that meet the aforementioned other criteria).

Comment: @TonyKelly - I posted an answer already, which I deleted when I saw Radim's suggestion (my answer used, in a similar way, the TRANSLATE function, but TRIM is even better). The Correct answer should belong to Radim. The syntax is trivial: `where ... AND TRIM(cust.customername) IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: This really smells wrong.  If it is a PK, it has to be unique and not null.

Comment: @EvilTeach - the OP just said (in a Comment) that the offending field is not the ID (presumably PK), but Customer **Name**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume with your query you want to do something like this:

```
AND (CustomerName NOT LIKE '%  %' OR CustomerName != '')
```

Warning! This is not going to give you a compilation error but it is not going to work work as you expect. Oracle is going to interpret '' as NULL and nothing is unequal to NULL (nothing is equal to NULL either). Therefore the second part of your condition is always going to be false which makes it useless. To achieve what you want you have to use

```
OR CustomerName IS NOT NULL
```

or as described by other above:

```
OR TRIM(CustomerName) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Therefore, the NOT NULL delimits those that are in fact blank, and the TRIM then deletes the spaces, making those entries that just contained spaces blank, thus leaving it victim to the NOT NULL delimitation, right?

I just want to understand...I try to learn from these experiences, not regurgitate answers.

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. You could leave out the TRIM() because if TRIM removes space the condition CustomerName NOT LIKE '%  %' would be true.

Comment: My overall statement now looks like :
       SELECT cust.CustomerID, cust.CustomerName
   FROM cust
   WHERE cust.StartDate Between '01-Jun-2017' AND '01-Sep-2017' AND cust.CustomerID Like '%100%' Or cust.CustomerID Like '%200%' AND TRIM(CustomerName IS NOT NULL)

Comment: @tonykelly and does this work?  if not what is the length(trim(customerName)) of a record that doesn't?

Comment: No. The syntax I gave you was wrong. My bad!  I fixed my post. But if you include "AND cust.CustomerID Like '%100%' Or cust.CustomerID Like '%200%'" in the where condition you are automatically excluding spaces only and NULLS. But you are not excluding "   200" or "200   ". If you want to exclude those you have to add AND CustomerID NOT LIKE '% %'.

Comment: @fhossfel CustomerID and CustomerName are different...I need the IDs that begin with 100 or 200 (which explains the CustomerID LIKE '%100%' etc..), but the CustomerName is different...i need to only select the remaining CustomerNames that are NOT blank or just spaces

Comment: Then TRIM(CustomerName) IS NOT NULL is the right condition. It means that if all leading and trailing spaces are removed there must still be something left of the string.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the below function will help you to solve the problem:

```
TRIM( [ [ LEADING | TRAILING | BOTH ] trim_character FROM ] string1 )
```

Also you probably need to wrap the above around

```
LENGTH( string1 )
```

Don't hesitate to ask me for any further clarifications!

Ted

Comment: If you can, please see my update. The issue is that sometimes, the CustomerName field has been entered as " " or " " or " " and I don't want those results.

Comment: Why do you need `LENGTH()`? `TRIM(...) is not null` is all that's needed.

Comment: Yes you are right LENGTH probably is not needed. Back to TRIM, how about TRIM(BOTH '-' FROM TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM x)) ?

Comment: The OP is **not** looking to treat the dash `-` in any particular way, he was just mentioning that the "valid" names may include letters, digits, and sometimes dashes. They don't have to be handled. Only spaces need to be handled. Then: by default, TRIM will trim from both sides (although in this problem it doesn't even matter), and also by default, TRIM will trim spaces. So `TRIM(customername)` alone, with no other arguments, suffices!

Comment: So I don't understand what the remaining open issue(s) are!?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will solve the problem as stated:

```
where customerId is not null
and customerId > ''
and customerId = , replace(customerId, ' ', '') -- this takes care of the spaces
```

Comment: This will return no rows, because `... > null` is **never** true, and in Oracle, `''` is the same as `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want parentheses in the right places:

```
SELECT cust.CustomerID, cust.CustomerName
FROM cust
WHERE cust.StartDate Between date '2017-06-01' and date '2017-09-01' and 
      (cust.CustomerID Like '%100%' Or cust.CustomerID Like '%200%')
```

The `like` pattern requires that the customer id has at least 100 or 200, so spaces and empty strings are not permitted.

You might also notice that I prefer date constants using ISO standard formats YYYY-MM-DD.

Or, if you prefer:

```
SELECT cust.CustomerID, cust.CustomerName
FROM cust
WHERE cust.StartDate Between date '2017-06-01' and date '2017-09-01' and 
      regexp_like(cust.CustomerID, '[12]00')
```

Comment: thanks. But I think I may have phrased my question wrongly. The first query runs fine. I need an ADDITIONAL AND condition where I am using NOT LIKE but I don't know the syntax.

Comment: The question is (and was from the beginning) about excluding rows where `customerid` is `null` or all-spaces. This answer has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

Best might be to use a regular expression:

```
AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE(CustomerName, '^[[:space:]]*$')
```